# Clojure Mock call to Java Object function

Tags: java, unit-testing, clojure

I have a function that makes a call to a service. I want to mock this API for unit testing to simulate two situations:

1. API succeeds, and returns nothing
2. API fails, and throws an exception

My sample code is given below:

```
(defn- get-client [] (client/getService))

(def get-client-memo (memoize get-client))

(defn- api
  [id1 id2]
   (.client_api (get-client-memo) id1 id2)
     (log/info "successfully deactivated"))
```

I figure, I can make use of with-redefs-fn to mock a function defined in clojure. But How do I mock the Java object and its API?

Thanks for your help,
Swagatika

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can't you just write a wrapper for the Java object and then mock that?

Comment: How about to redef api-fn itself, if it contains purely side-effects it's even better

Comment: Anybody get anywhere with this?
Everywhere I look it says to wrap the java calls in clojure functions then mock the clojure functions for testing.